# C++ Setting Speed of While Loop per Second

Tags: c++, loops, time, while-loop, modifier

I am relatively new to C++, so I don't have a huge amount of experience. I have learned Python, and I am trying to make an improved version of a Python code I wrote in C++. However, I want it to work in real time, so I need to set the speed of a While loop. I'm sure there is an answer, but I couldn't find it. I want a comparable code to this:

```
rate(timeModifier * (1/dt))
```

This was the code I used in Python. I can set a variable dt to make calculations more precise, and timeModifier to double or triple the speed (1 sets it to realtime). This means that the program will go through the loop 1/dt times per second. I understand I can include time.h at the header, but I guess I am too new to C++ to understand how to transfer this to my needs.

Comment: Use a sleep function to wait until you are ready for the next iteration

Comment: Careful: depending on what you are doing (physics simulation, game loop) calling `sleep` is moderately horrible advice. Rather, you want [either framerate-dependent calculations or fixed time steps with which get called in variable intervals](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1589/4661).

Comment: While the meaning of the term "realtime" is more than a little nebulous, it probably doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it the same manner in C++. You need to manually call some kind of sleep function in calculation loop, `Sleep` on Windows or `usleep` on *NIX.

Comment: Yep that's all I needed. Sleep() works in the opposite way from the Python version, but it works for my needs.

Comment: I don't recommend using `Sleep()` functions since It'd block the whole application from running and gives inaccurate time, However, it's absolutely inappropriate for real-time things.

Answer (score 7):

You could write your own timer class:

```
#include <ctime>

class Timer {
    private:
        unsigned long startTime;
    public:
        void start() {
            startTime = clock();
        }

        unsigned long elapsedTime() {
            return ((unsigned long) clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        }

        bool isTimeout(unsigned long seconds) {
            return seconds >= elapsedTime();
        }
};


int main() 
{
    unsigned long dt = 10; //in seconds
    Timer t;
    t.start();

    while(true) 
    {
        if(t.elapsedTime() < dt) 
        {
            //do something to pass time as a busy-wait or sleep
        }
        else 
        {
            //do something else
                    t = Timer(); //reset the timer
        }
    }
}
```

Note that busy-waits are discouraged, since they will hog the CPU.  If you don't need to do anything, use the [`sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command(Windows) or [`usleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/usleep.html) ( Linux).  For more information on making timers in C++, see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/317/).

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've done something like this, but something like this will work:

```
#include <time.h>

time_t t2, t1 = time(NULL);

while(CONDITIONS)
{
    time_t t2 = time(NULL);
    if(difftime(t2, t1) > timeModifier)
    {
        //DO the stuff!
        t1 = time(NULL);
    }
}
```

I should note, however, that I'm not familiar with the precision of this method, I think it measures the difference in seconds.

If you need something more precise, use the `clock()` function which has the number of milliseconds since 12:00 AM beginning January 1, 1980, to the nearest 10 milliseconds.
Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <time.h>

clock_t t2, t1 = clock();

while(CONDITIONS)
{
    t2 = clock();
    if((t2-t1) > someTimeElapsed*timeModifier)
    {
        //DO the stuff!
        t1 = clock());
    }
}
```

Update:
You can even yield the CPU to other threads and processes by adding this after the end of the `if` statement:

```
else
{
    usleep(10000); //sleep for ten milliseconds (chosen because of precision on clock())
}
```

Comment: you appear to read from t1 before assigning, and  there should be an else containing a sleep before you get a +1

Comment: @MooingDuck I added a note, but for me it depends on what the program is doing whether or not I would want it to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the accuracy you need, and your platform, you could use `usleep` This allows you to set the pause time down to microseconds:

```
 #include <unistd.h>

 int usleep(useconds_t useconds);
```

Remember that your loop will always take longer than this because of the inherent processingtime of the rest of the loop but it's a start. For anything more accurate,you'd probably need to look at timer based callbacks.

Comment: You should mention that windows has a different command for this.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I did mention that it was platform dependent. I'm not sure what Windows provides as I don't use it. :)

Comment: The other answers mention the Windows equivalent: `sleep` :D

Answer (score 0):

You should really create a new thread and have it do the timing so that it remains unaffected by the processing work done in the loop.

**WARNING:** Pseudo code... just to give you an idea of how to start.

```
Thread* tThread = CreateTimerThread(1000);
tThread->run();
while( conditionNotMet() )
{
    tThread->waitForTimer();
    doWork();
}
```

`CreateTimerThread()` should return the thread object you want, and run would be something like:

```
run()
{
    while( false == shutdownLatch() )
    {
        Sleep( timeout );
        pulseTimerEvent();
    }
}

waitForTimer()
{
    WaitForSingleObject( m_handle );
    return;
}
```

Comment: Maybe, but it would remove the "worry" of keeping pegged times and calculating sleep loops. Nice into to multi-threading. Not that hard these days with the apache decaf, boost and Intel TBB libraries.
Besides look at how clean the code becomes... :)

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows you can use [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), while polling the time (e.g. within another while loop) call `Sleep(0)` to allow other threads to continue operation.

Remember `Sleep` is highly inaccurate. For full control just run a loop without operations, however you'll use 100% of the CPU. To relax the strain on the CPU you can call `Sleep(10)` etc.